# Changing the value of an option trhough javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two option fields, depending on the selection on the *first one*, it changes the options for the *second*.

Currently the values for the *second field* are numerical but I would like them to be the same as the text option because it is going to be sent in an email.

**Javascript code:**

```
var affiliatesAndCompanies = {};
affiliatesAndCompanies['Auto Industry'] = ['Company','Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company3'];
affiliatesAndCompanies['Door-to-door Sales'] = ['Company', 'Company 5', 'Company 6', 'Company 7'];
affiliatesAndCompanies['Independent'] = ['Company', 'Company 9', 'Company 10'];
affiliatesAndCompanies['Mortgage Officer'] = ['Company', 'Company 12', 'Company 13'];
affiliatesAndCompanies['Real Estate Agent'] = ['Company', 'Company 15', 'Company 16'];
affiliatesAndCompanies['Seminar Servicers'] = ['Company', 'Company 18', 'Company 19'];

function ChangeaffiliationList() {
    var affiliatesList = document.getElementById("affiliation");
    var companiesList = document.getElementById("companies");
    var selAffiliation = affiliatesList.options[affiliatesList.selectedIndex].value;

    while (companiesList.options.length) {
        companiesList.remove(0);
    }

    var affiliates = affiliatesAndCompanies[selAffiliation];
    if (affiliates) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < affiliates.length; i++) {
            var affiliate = new Option(affiliates[i], i);
            companiesList.options.add(affiliate);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<select class="validate-required" name="parent-affiliate" id="affiliation" onchange="ChangeaffiliationList()">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Area of affiliation</option>
  <option value="Auto Industry">Auto Industry</option>
  <option value="Door-to-door Sales">Door-to-door Sales</option>
  <option value="Independent">Independent</option>
  <option value="Mortgage Officer">Mortgage Officer</option>
  <option value="Real Estate Agent">Real Estate Agent</option>
  <option value="Seminar Servicers">Seminar Servicers</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select-option col-md-6 p0"> <i class="ti-angle-down"></i>
  <select class="validate-required" name="parent-affiliate-options" id="companies">
    <option selected="selected" value="no-selection">Company</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

look at the docs for Option... you are using i as the value.

```
new Option(affiliates[i], affiliates[i]);
```

if you wanted the value to be the same as the text.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I am not a js developer, that is why I am having a hard time understanding them documentation. But your trick worked. Thanks